# How can I download all files from Amazon S3 that are in a folder that was created last month?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto, aws-cli

How can I download a folder from Amazon S3 that was created last month until the present?

I have this code using boto:

```
for key in bucket.list():
   if last_month < dateutil.parser(key.last_modified).month:
      key.get_contents_to_filename(local_path + key.name)
```

The problem is the loop will take a long time because it's comparing each file in the folder. I only want to compare the folder timestamp.

If there's a way using the AWS CLI much better.

Comment: um change your search directory to timestamp?

Comment: Have you timed it, or do you merely think that it would be slow?

Comment: No but it really take long.. I have a bunch of folders and each folders contain 10 - 30 files.

Comment: Have you tried using the AWS CLI?  The s3 command allows you to navigate an S3 bucket like a directory structure if your object naming scheme incorporates that.  Just try do an "aws s3 ls s3://<bucketname> and see what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

**Amazon S3 does not use directories.** It is a flat storage structure.

To give the appearance of directories, **paths are prepended to the Key** (filename) of an Object (file).

For example, an object called `cat.jpg` stored in a directory called `animals` would actually have a Key (filename) of `animals/cat.jpg`.

Since the directories do not exist, there is no way to retrieve properties from a directory.

(BTW, there is a concept of "common prefixes" that can work like directories when referring to multiple files, but it still isn't an actual directory.)

Comment: Yah I think you're right.. What I just did is get all the folders in the directory and get the lastModified date in the file. I just considered the lastModified date as a timestamp for the folder.